# How to count the total reactions on a message? (Discord.Js)

Tags: discord.js

For context, I don't mean reactions.cache.size. Instead I want to find if there's a way to get the total amount of reactions on a message.

[image]

For example, I don't want this to return the number 2, like what cache.size would do. Instead I want it to return 3. how can I count the total amount of reactions on a singular message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const emojisList = ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣', '4️⃣', '5️⃣', '6️⃣', '7️⃣', '8️⃣', '9️⃣']


 do {
                            var reactionCount = reactions.get(emojisList[i]);
                            //console.log('Reaction count is' + reactionCount.count)
                            reactionArray.push(reactionCount.count)
                            //console.log("Total reactions is "+total)
                            var percentage = '‎‎‏‏‎ ‎'
                            resultsEmbed.addField(`The option *${questionOptionsArray[i]}* got a total of ` + reactionArray[i] + ' votes.', percentage)
                            i++
                            console.log(`i = ${i}`)
                        }
                        while (i < reactions.size)
```

This allows me to do it within a loop. I counted it referencing the array I stored the emojis within. Because I don't know how many emojis will be there, I had to do this loop and have it continue until it's exhausted the amount of reactions on the message. It's probably not the most optimal way to do it, but I couldn't find any other way with the way my program works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reduce function of the map() object.

Here is an example:

```js
client.channels.cache.get("Your Channel ID").messages.fetch("Your Message ID").then(msg => {
  let totalReactionsCount = msg.reactions.cache.map(reaction => reaction.count).reduce(function(tot, arr) {
    return tot + arr;
  },0);
});
```

This will return the total number of reactions of the message.